# Spring Boot PUT and DELETE requests returning 403 after installing nginx reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, nginx

After putting my Spring Boot REST application behind an nginx reverse proxy, all `PUT` and `DELETE` requests are returning `403 Forbidden`. `POST` and `GET` requests are working fine. What could be the reason for this?

Here's the nginx configuration file:

```
server {
  # IP v4
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  # IP v6
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name    XXX.com www.XXX.com;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/XXX-dev_chain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/XXX-dev.key;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
      proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you need to set `proxy_http_version 1.1;` in your reverse proxy configuration as described here https://serverfault.com/questions/391577/put-and-delete-methods-in-nginx?

Comment: @GregorZurowski thanks. Just tried it but it doesn't seem to make a difference.